# Finding an entity that contain only some others entities

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an association like this :

Chatroom >----< User

So a Chatroom can contains multiple users, and a User can belong to multiple Chatrooms.

Now I want to select all the chatrooms that contains a couple of user, and only this couple.

I tried some solutions, like this one :

```
    public function findByUsers($firstUser, $secondUser){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.users LIKE :firstUser')
        ->andwhere('c.users LIKE :secondUser')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'firstUser' => $firstUser,
            'secondUser' => $secondUser
        ));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But It doesn't work and return me that kind of error :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 52 near 'users LIKE :firstUser': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Some users encountering this error resolved it by adding IDENTITY before the query selector, but I don't understand how to apply it in my case.

So, did someone know how I can get all the chatrooms containing my couple of users ?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT : Adding the doctrine relation annotations

User.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Chatroom", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="chatrooms_users",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="chatroom_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $chatrooms;
```

Chatroom.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="chatrooms")
 */
private $users;
```

Comment: Well is there an entity to resolve the many to many or does chatroom get repeated for each user and each user repeated for each chatroom?  in SQL I would resolve this by doing a `GROUP BY Room_ID having count(Distinct user_ID) = (Select count(1) From Room where USER_ID in (A,B))`  This way i compare to total count of users for room vs just the 2; ensuring the room only has those 2 users, no more, no less.  Not sure how it would work in doctrine/sympony.

Comment: There isn't entity for the relation, each user has a chatrooms (ManyToMany) property, and each chatroom has a users (ManyToMany) property. Your solution SQL should work, and maybe I'll use it if there's no way to do the job directly with doctrine entities.

Comment: It would make it easier to help you, if you would post those parts of your entities including the doctrine comments/yml or whatever you used to tell the ORM how they are mapped. Is users an array of string and $firstUser a string too as the "LIKE" in your statement implies?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's done ! users is a collection of entities -> all the users in the chatrooms. $firstUser and $secondUser are both user entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was :

```
public function findByUsers($ids)
{
    $count = count($ids);
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('chatroom');
    $qb->select('chatroom')
        ->join('chatroom.users', 'u')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(u) AS HIDDEN ucount')
        ->groupBy('chatroom.id')
        ->having('ucount = :count')
        ->setParameter('count', $count);

    foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
        $qb->andWhere(':id' . $key . ' MEMBER OF chatroom.users')
            ->setParameter('id'.$key, (int) $id);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Pass an array of users id (or simply users with some modifications), and the function returns the list of chatrooms that contains **only these users**